Show/movie about trolls running their own radio station?
I'm not sure if it was a movie or a series as we only got 1 VHS tape.
What I remember is that the show used what I think were puppet trolls who ran a radio station out from a tree(s). I also remember they did covers of well-known songs. Problem is I don't known any of their names but I have heard them in time. I remember who I think is the leader always wearing sunglasses because he showed up a lot of the time.


Sounds like "Trollies Radio Show Sing-a-long".
It was a direct-to-video musical with puppet trolls singing hits as well as original songs. The troll radio station featured in the programme was called "W-TROLL", and the DJs were Rock ‘n’ Troll and Cherry Troll Trollie.

Read more about the show here and watch a clip. You'll find lots more on YouTube.
